# Exporting Blender animation to dae for Android viewing

Tags: animation

I need help in exporting animation to dae and view it in the android app.
(I am open to any suggestion on ways to share the animation)

Current problem
1. Mesh/colour are not included in the dae exported.
2. The model leg is stretch far.

Here are my exported dae, blender file and app to view it

[dae & blender](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rl1o4u891ccddsf/AAD1fOXmeMCk1bds_wC1f6ATa?dl=0)

[Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.andresoviedo.dddmodel2)